# Invert colors when plotting a PNG file using matplotlib

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I'm trying to display a PNG file using matplotlib and of course, python. For this test, I've generated the following image:
[image: Original File]

Now, I load and transform the image into a multidimensional numpy matrix:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

cube = cv2.imread('Graphics/Display.png')
plt.imshow(cube)
plt.ion()
```

When I try to plot that image in matplotlib, the colors are inverted:[image: Plot]

If the matrix does not have any modifications, why the colors in the plot are wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At very least, the colors here aren't inverted.  black still corresponds to black, green to green.  I have a feeling that matplotlib is mapping the values to a palette and coloring according to the value on the palette.

Comment: @mgilson If matplotlib is mapping the colors according to a palette, How can I can modify that palette?

Comment: I'd start by looking [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html) and [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/show_colormaps.html)

Comment: The original PNG you posted has shape (923,800,4). I wonder why `imshow` is indicating `cube` has shape ~ (1400,1200,4)?

Comment: Looks like your R/G/B values are reversed. Don't know enough about matplotlib to say why.

Comment: @unutbu I think that the server rescaled the image when i uploaded it, the original size is of (1168, 1347, 3) without the alpha.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It appears that you may somehow have `RGB` switched with `BGR`.  Notice that your greens are retained but all the blues turned to red.  If `cube` has shape (M,N,3), try swapping `cube[:,:,0]` with `cube[:,:,2]`.  You can do that with `numpy` like so:

```
rgb = numpy.fliplr(cube.reshape(-1,3)).reshape(cube.shape)
```

From the [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#Mat%20imread%28const%20string&%20filename,%20int%20flags%29)  documentation:

> Note: In the case of color images, the decoded images will have the
>   channels stored in B G R order.

Comment: Good workaround, but the question still remains: why did it happen?

Comment: There is an easier way to flip the color channels:
cube = cube[..., ::-1]

Comment: @Mark Ransom OpenCV is quite old, and these color orders were chosen way back then before RGB became the de facto standard order, BGR made more sense since it is in alphabetical order, and was widely used at the time.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Well, a lot of products used BGR back then, RGB was not as universal as it is today, products like the Game Gear, the wonderSwan and more importantly for this subject, camera makers, image software providers and Windows itself all used BGR, and I don't need to explain to you why the last three were an important decision point for a library like OpenCV. For more details see this: https://www.learnopencv.com/why-does-opencv-use-bgr-color-format/:

Comment: @Kaaf thanks for the link.  I knew that BGR was used by Windows, but that wasn't until the '80's.  I still don't have a single example of it being used before then.

Answer (score 18):

Try:

```
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(cube, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

Comment: Nice elegant solution!

Comment: wonder if there isnt a cmap kwarg solution to this, such as cmap=bgr

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the problem is that numpy arrays are in BGR format, but matplotlib expects the arrays to be ordered in a different way.

You are looking for [`scipy.misc.toimage`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.toimage.html):

```
import scipy.misc
rgb = scipy.misc.toimage(cube)
```

Alternatively, you can use `scipy.misc.imshow()`.

Answer (score 0):

Color image loaded by OpenCV is in BGR mode. However, Matplotlib displays in RGB mode.
So we need to convert the image from BGR to RGB:

```
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(cube, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```