# Keras showing images from data generator

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, neural-network, keras

I am using image generator for keras like this:

```
val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        path+'/valid',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=batch_size,)

x,y = val_generator.next()
for i in range(0,1):
    image = x[i]
    plt.imshow(image.transpose(2,1,0))
    plt.show()
```

This shows wrong colors:
[image]

I have two questions.

1. How to fix the problem
2. How to get file names of the files (so that I can read it myself from something like matplotlib)

Edit : this is what my datagen looks like

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=3,
#     featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    fill_mode='nearest',
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True
)
```

Edit 2 :

After following Marcin's answer :

```
image = 255 - image
```

I get normal colors , but there are still some weird colors:

[image]

Comment: could you show the code for datagen, too ? For example, there is an option channel_shift_range. By default it's 0, but if you've set it to something else, it might mess with the colors.

Comment: and I think you should split this question. The color distortion is about Keras. Getting filenames from a directory is a different question entirely. This is just python standard lib.

Comment: that being said: I like the glob module a lot. glob.glob("path/*.png") will return a list of all .png files in a directory

Comment: take a look. 
@ihk i want file names that datagen processes ,not just files from a directory

Comment: I see. still I think this should be two separate questions

Comment: @ihk , tbh the 2nd question was a fallback if the first question doesnt have a valid solution.

Comment: this code gives me: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'imshow'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There are at least three ways to have this twisted colors. So:

   - one option is that you need to switch a color ordering like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387668/invert-colors-when-plotting-a-png-file-using-matplotlib).
   - second is that you might have your pictures made to be a negative (every channels gets transformed by `255 - x` transformation) this sometimes happens when it comes to using some GIS libraries.
   - you could also use a `score/255` transformation.

   You need to check which options happens in your case.
2. In order to get the images on your own I usually use (when your folder has a format suitable for a Keras `flow_from_directory`) I usually use the mix of `os.listdir` and `os.path.join` by :

   ```
   list_of_labels = os.listdir(path_to_dir_with_label_dirs)
   for label in list_of_labels:
       current_label_dir_path = os.path.join(path_to_dir_with_label_dirs, label
       list_of_images = os.listdir(current_label_dir_path)
       for image in list_of_images:
           current_image_path = os.path.join(current_label_dir_path, image)
           image = open(current_image_path) # use the function which you want.
   ```

Comment: I followed both suggestions , but it still doesnt seem to work:
i tried:
`for i in range(0,1):
    image = x[i]
#     image = image - 255
    rgb = np.fliplr(image.reshape(-1,3)).reshape(image.shape)
    plt.imshow(image.transpose(1,2,0))
    print(y[i])
    plt.show()`

Comment: Try '255 - image'.first.

Comment: im sorry , my equation was wrong. I did x = x-255 where it should be x = 255-x. 
I see normal colors , but i still have weird colors at some areas. Please see the edit.

Comment: Try turning off all image transformation - I guess this is the reason behind weird colors

Comment: I did `val_generator = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(
        path+'/valid',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=batch_size,)`

But i still get the same weird dots

Comment: and what are the original image sizes? Maybe resizing them is the problem.

Comment: The original images are unequal , but i thought resizing would be fine :( . 
What is more weird is , if i use scipy.misc.imshow() the images are fine (dont have to do -255)

Comment: It's probably due to smoothing of image during printing. I wouldn't be worried about this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133357/discussion-between-marcin-mozejko-and-harvey-slash).

Comment: all I wanted to do was print out my predictions along with the actual photo (to display in jupyter notebook)

Answer (score 9):

The dtype of your image array is 'float32', just convert it into 'uint8':

```
plt.imshow(image.astype('uint8'))
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem as OP and solved it by rescaling the pixels from 0-255 to 0-1.

Keras' ImageDataGenerator takes a 'rescale' parameter, which I set to (1/255). This produced images with expected colors

```
image_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=(1/255))
```

Answer (score 1):

The color problem is rather strange.
I'll try to reproduce it once I have access to my linux machine.

For the filename part of the question, I would like to propose a small change to the Keras sourcecode:

You might want to take a look at this file:
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py
It contains the image preprocessing routines.

Look at line 820, the `next()` function of the `DirectoryIterator`: this is called to get new images from the directory.

Inside of that function, look at line 838, if `save_to_dir` has been set to a path, the generator will output the augmented images to this path, for debugging purposes.
The name of the augmented image is a mixture of an index and a hash. Not useful for you.

But you can change the code quite easily:

```
filenames=[] #<-------------------------------------------- new code
for i, j in enumerate(index_array):
    fname = self.filenames[j]
    img = load_img(os.path.join(self.directory, fname),
                   grayscale=grayscale,
                   target_size=self.target_size)
    x = img_to_array(img, dim_ordering=self.dim_ordering)
    x = self.image_data_generator.random_transform(x)
    x = self.image_data_generator.standardize(x)

    filenames.append(fname) # <-----------------------------store the used image's name
    batch_x[i] = x
# optionally save augmented images to disk for debugging purposes
if self.save_to_dir:
    for i in range(current_batch_size):
        img = array_to_img(batch_x[i], self.dim_ordering, scale=True)
        #fname = '{prefix}_{index}_{hash}.{format}'.format(prefix=self.save_prefix,
        #                                                  index=current_index + i,
        #                                                  hash=np.random.randint(1e4),
        #                                                  format=self.save_format)
        fname=filenames[i] # <------------------------------ use the stored code instead
        img.save(os.path.join(self.save_to_dir, fname))
```

**Now the augmented image is saved with the original filename.**

This should allow you to save the images under their original filenames.
Ok, how do you actually inject this into the Keras souce ?

Do it like this:

1. clone Keras: `git clone https://github.com/fchollet/keras`
2. go to the sourcefile I linked above. Make the change.
3. Trick your python code to import the changed code instead of the version installed by pip.

.

```
# this is the path to the cloned repository
# if you cloned it next to your script
# then just use keras/
# if it's one folder above
# then use ../keras/
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd() + "/path/to/keras/")

import keras
```

Now the `DirectoryIterator` is your patched version.

I hope that this works, I'm currently on windows. My python stack is only on the linux machine. There might be a small syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

```
from skimage import io

def imshow(image_RGB):
  io.imshow(image_RGB)
  io.show()

x,y = train_generator.next()

for i in range(0,11):
    image = x[i]
    imshow(image)
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just a bit of advice if you are using `test_batches=Imagedatagenerator().flow` from directory. If you use this to feed a predict generator make sure you set `shuffle=false` to maintain a correlation between the file and the associated prediction. If you have files numerically labelled in the directory for example as *1.jpg*, *2.jpg* etc. The images are not fetched as you might think. They are fetched in the order:
*1.jpg*, *10.jpg*, *2.jpg*, *20.jpg* etc. This makes it hard to match a prediction to a specific file. You can get around this by using 0's padding for example *01.jpg*, *02.jpg* etc. On the second part of the question "how can I get the files the generator produces you can get these files as follows:

```
for file in datagen.filenames:
        file_names.append(file)
```