# Matplotlib displays not right color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to display an image using matplotlib. I want to split the channels of image and display them separately. only if I want to display the red pixels does it show them in blue. And the other way around. The green color is going well. By the way, if I display them with cv2.imshow () everything is fine.

```
empty_image = img.copy()
empty_image = np.zeros(img.shape, img.dtype)

channel=empty_image.copy()
channel[:,:,0]=img[:,:,0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(channel, cmap="binary")
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

this is because OpenCV load images in **BGR** (Blue Green Red) instead of the commonly used RGB (Red Green Blue). Matplotlib displays in **RGB**.

So according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45977060/13540083) post, you can use `plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))` to convert the colors from BGR to RGB so Matplotlib will read it fine.

Hopefully this helps.